# Finding value of trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

If $\sin^{2} \theta_{1}+\sin^{2} \theta_{2}+\sin^{2} \theta_{3} = 0$, then which of the following is not a possible value of  $\cos\theta_{1}+\cos \theta_{2}+\cos \theta_{3}$

Options->

(i)$3$

(i)$-3$

(i)$-1$

(iv)$-2$

My try:-

$\sin^{2} \theta_{1}+\sin^{2} \theta_{2}+\sin^{2} \theta_{3} = 0$

=> $(1-\cos^{2} \theta_{1})+(1-\cos^{2} \theta_{2})+(1-\cos^{2} \theta_{3}) = 0$

=> $-\cos^{2} \theta_{1}-\cos^{2} \theta_{2}-\cos^{2} \theta_{3} = -3$

=> $\cos^{2} \theta_{1}+\cos^{2} \theta_{2}+\cos^{2} \theta_{3} = 3$

Comment: If the first equation is true, then you must have $\sin \theta_k = 0$ for all $k$. If this is true, you must have $\cos \theta_k = \pm 1$. So the question is, what values can the expression $\pm 1 \pm 1 \pm1$ take?

Comment: @copper.hat How did you deduce that $\sin \theta_{k} = 0$ for all $k$ ??

Comment: If $a^2+b^2+c^2 = 0$ then we know that $a=b=c= 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $sin^2 (\phi) \ge 0$  for all $\phi $. So if $sin^2(\theta_1)+sin^2(\theta_2)+sin^2(\theta_3) = 0$, what does that tell you?